# history pushes after replace

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I'm using React Router in my app. I have a code fragment, that resolves a promise and pushes to a new URL after that. However, I'm catching errors on the next site that gets pushed towards, with `componentDidCatch`. This method replaces then the current URL. I'm listening to the router history, but it seems that the queue of the history is a bit off (notice that the actual navigation is correct!):

```
history.listen(({ pathname }) => console.log(pathname));
Promise.resolve().then(() => history.push('/next'));

// on /next
history.replace('/fallback');
```

I expect an output like this:

```
/next
/fallback
```

But what I receive is this:

```
/fallback
/next
```

Is there a way to achieve the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => history.push('/next')).then(()=> history.replace('/fallback'));
```

Comment: Please add some explanations

Comment: Hm, my code already works this way. Notice, that I'm using a router here, so the two code fragments are occuring in non-related components.